# Visual Studio - change color of "line changes indicator" next to line numbers

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to change the color of these lines in Visual Studio. Is there a setting to do this?

[image]

These lines indicate that the line of code has changes (green=saved, yellow=unsaved). Or maybe someone at least knows what these lines are called.

Comment: If anyone wonders how to enable this color column next to line numbers, for VS 2017, it is in: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> Display -> Selection Margin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors>Text Editor>Track Changes before save

[image]